# Is there no way to specify a relative path in PyCharm's Sphinx "Run Configuration"?

Tags: python, documentation-generation, pycharm

I'm setting up documentation tasks for a number of projects a manage using PyCharm, but an running into an obstacle. It appears that there is no way to specify a *relative* path in the "configuration" dialog for the task. For example, I can't to this:

[image]

Can that be correct? If so, it means I need to create a different "Run Configuration" for each project, even though they all do exactly the same thing. Is there a way around this — by placing the documentation files in some default subdirectory of my projects, or setting some other option of variable?

Answer (score 1):

Since run configurations are specific to a project, there is no benefit in specifying a relative path in the UI. Internally, all paths under the project root are stored as relative, even though they're displayed as absolute in the UI.

Comment: There is if your project is on a USB key for example. Or if you wish to copy the folder structure to someone including those files.